# Firestore - I cannot see the data page on one of my databases

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I have two databases in Firestore.  One is TwitterClone.  The second is memorials.  See image 1. When I click on TwitterClone database and select Firestore Database on the side panel, I get the data page which displays the records that I have added to the database. See image 2.  When I select the `memorials` database and select Firestore Database on the side panel  I get a page that gives me the option to create a database. See image 3.  I created a program that printed a message that said it successfully added a record to the memorials database, so I believe it is populated. How can I get to the data page for the memorials database?

[image: firestore console]

[image: data page displayed for twitterClone database]

[image: this page was displayed instead of the data page for the memorials database]

I was able to navigate to the data page for one of my databases and then duplicated the steps for the memorials database and the data page did not display.  Then I navigated to the data page for the twitterClone database and then changed the database in the drop-down at the top of the data page and still the data page for memorials was not displayed

Answer (score 0):

> I have two databases in Firestore. One is TwitterClone. The second is memorials.

No, the Firebase Console indicates that you have two different Firebase projects.

> When I select the `memorials` database and select Firestore Database on the side panel I get a page that gives me the option to create a database.

Yes, it gives you the option to create a database because there is no database yet created.

> I created a program that printed a message that said it successfully added a record to the `memorials` database.

The `memorials` is **not** a database, is a Firebase project. It's true that can use a Firestore database within this project, but only if you create one. In your `memorials` project, there is no Firestore database in which you can add documents. So most likely, you're writing somewhere else. Remember that if you want to write data into the Firestore database that belongs to another Firebase project, you have to use in your client project the JSON file that belongs to that project.

Comment: Hey Edward. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thanks again.  You pointed me in the right direction.   I am current reviewing the documentation provided on Firestore and Firebase.  I should be able to find the step I missed.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.